# SSRS - How to reference a specific field's value based to be able to use it in another field?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a dataset which gives me all the results I need in order to formulate my table in my report.

Dataset Returns this:

```
District    Location         ChlorineValue
-------------------------------------------
Belize1     WTPA             3.4
Belize1     WTPB             2.6
Belize1     Sandhill Road    0.5
```

OK so currently in my SSRS report I have when it gets to the row with "Sandhill Road" under "Location", it displays "Sandhill" as the "District".

What I want to do is in the SSRS Tablix, I want it to display two rows under "Sandhill" (my SSRS report is grouped by the "District" column, a Row Group) with the values for "WTPA" and "WTPB" under the "Chlorine Value" column.

Basically I want my result to be:

```
District    Location         ChlorineValue
-------------------------------------------
Belize1     WTPA             3.4
Belize1     WTPB             2.6
Sandhill    WTPA             3.4
Sandhill    WTPB             2.6
```

I've read about using Variables but I can't get the Report Properties to reference my dataset which contains the values.

Comment: Can you change your query to get the desired resultset? In that case, you can directly bind it Tablix in report.

Comment: I don't understand the logic that gets you from your dataset to you desired results. Your dataset returns 3 rows, but you want to output 4. You want district to show "Sandhill" but that value is not in the dataset? I think you need to add more info to explain how the logic is supposed to work.

Comment: @iVad I was initially trying to do this but I could not figure out how I would formulate a query to accomplish this, however I will try to solve this on the database level.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Yes I want to repeat the WTPA and WTPB values under "Sandhill", I had already figured out how to display "Sandhill" under district when necessary but I have not figured out how to include the WTPA and WTPB values (that is the ChlorineValue)

Comment: Add some more details about your database table and queries you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd need to do this in the SQL with a UNION:

```
SELECT District, Location, ChlorineValue
FROM T1 
WHERE T1.Location NOT LIKE 'SANDHILL%'

UNION

SELECT T1.Location, T2.Location, T1.ChlorineValue 
FROM T1 
JOIN (
    SELECT * 
    FROM T1 
    WHERE T1.Location NOT LIKE 'SANDHILL%'
) T2 ON T2.District = T1.District
WHERE T1.Location LIKE 'SANDHILL%'
```

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned that the above table was only a section of the entire table to demonstrate what I need to accomplish. I have other locations that I'd need to single out in in the same manner like what I have demonstrated above. I have considered using a switch.

Comment: I think you'll need to create the extra rows in the SQL - I don't see how you can have SSRS create them. You might be able to adjust the WHERE clause to isolate your locations.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but the UNION idea really worked out for the most part.